# How to write a function that will execute itself at the given time and date. discord.py (background tasks)

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I tried this,but I am getting the error: saying sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sometask' was never awaited

```
date_time_str = 30/5/21 03:48:00
time_for_thing_to_happen = time(21,20) 

async def sometask():

    valid_channel = client.get_channel(814734276439441461)
    while True:

        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        date = now.date()
        if now.time() > time_for_thing_to_happen:
            date = now.date() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            await valid_channel.send('its time')


        then = datetime.datetime.combine(date, time_for_thing_to_happen)
        await discord.utils.sleep_until(then)
        print("it's 12 o'clock")
```

Comment: Could you please provide your code in text form instead of an image?

Comment: @GeorgyKopshteyn I updated the question and added the text.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [background tasks](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/background_task_asyncio.py).

In your `on_ready` event, put this line:

```py
client.bg_task = client.loop.create_task(sometask())
```

This will allow you to run your coroutine at the correct times.

Comment: @HaiderNawaz Then what's the issue? This answer will fix the error you have in your question